# Opening multiple Browsers in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Open the same **URL test** *i-e opening the google link with multiple number of browsers* lets say 20. I want to do this in C# and found various blogs and tutorials on multiple windows handling but didn't get the right answer.

Comment: Did you try anything out of all those tutorials ?

Comment: I have tried looping over the driver instance initialization